# Getting an enum from a class with multiple enums

Tags: java, enums

I have a class that looks like this:

```
public class Catalog {

    public enum Table1 implements IExcelEnum{
            Name, Date, Id
    }

    public enum Table2 IExcelEnum {
        ...
    }
}
```

I can get to the enum Table1, such as:

```
System.out.println(Catalog.Table2.Name.value());
```

But what I want to do is to be able to feed a String or an identifier and get the enum back out so that I can reference it when creating my data object. so for example:

```
Data dataCol1 = new Data(Catalog.getEnum("Table1"), ArrayList<String> values);
```

I have an interface called IExcelEnum that does not have any fields, its just so I can generically type my enums so my data structure is willing to accept any of them.

What is the cleanest way to do this?

Comment: I don't get what you are trying to accomplish. What if you had multiple fields in `Catalog` of type `T1`? Which one do you expect to be returned by the call to `Catalog.getEnum("T1")`?

Comment: sorry if my variables are not clear, I'll change them to be more descriptive, there are multiple enums and I want to be able to get each one with a function call.

Comment: So, you want to get the Enum class itself?

Comment: I want to be able to pass Table1 to another class and have it be able to iterate through it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to use reflection like this:

```
    public class Catalog
{
    public interface I
    {
    }

    public enum T1 implements I
    {
        A, B, C;
    }

    public enum T2 implements I
    {
        D, E, F;
    }

    public static void main (String [] args) throws Exception
    {
        String name = "T1";

        Class <? extends I> c =
            (Class <? extends I>)Class.forName (
                Catalog.class.getName () + "$" + name);

        I [] values = (I [])c.getMethod ("values").invoke (null);

        for (I i: values)
            System.out.println (i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Kind of obnoxious that we have to do this, but this solved my problem.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean `Catalog.T1.valueOf("TC1")`?

In Java, all enums implement the `valueOf(String)` method, [see here.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#valueOf)